# Cross join (Cartesian product) of a list with a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, cross-join

I have a list and a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
work_station = ['A','B','C']
name = ['Mike','Tom','Scott','Tracy']
salary = ['60000','50000','100000','90000']
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':name,'salary':salary})
```

I want to cross join work_station and df together so the output looks like following:

```
station     Name    salary
  A         Mike    60000
  A         Tom     50000
  A         Scott   100000
  A         Tracy   90000
  B         Mike    60000
  B         Tom     50000
  B         Scott   100000
  B         Tracy   90000
  C         Mike    60000
  C         Tom     50000
  C         Scott   100000
  C         Tracy   90000
```

I tried to use * function

```
df1 = work_station * salary
```

but it's not working becase

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy peasy, use `concat` with a `keys` argument:

```
(pd.concat([df] * len(work_station), keys=work_station)
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
   .rename_axis('station')
   .reset_index()
)

   station   name  salary
0        A   Mike   60000
1        A    Tom   50000
2        A  Scott  100000
3        A  Tracy   90000
4        B   Mike   60000
5        B    Tom   50000
6        B  Scott  100000
7        B  Tracy   90000
8        C   Mike   60000
9        C    Tom   50000
10       C  Scott  100000
11       C  Tracy   90000
```

---

You can also go the `merge` route with a cartesian product:

```
(pd.DataFrame(work_station, columns=['station'])
  .assign(foo=1)
  .merge(df.assign(foo=1))
  .drop('foo', 1)
)

   station   name  salary
0        A   Mike   60000
1        A    Tom   50000
2        A  Scott  100000
3        A  Tracy   90000
4        B   Mike   60000
5        B    Tom   50000
6        B  Scott  100000
7        B  Tracy   90000
8        C   Mike   60000
9        C    Tom   50000
10       C  Scott  100000
11       C  Tracy   90000
```